# Resetting TaskFactory Indexer?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, task-parallel-library

with

```
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(Consume);
        }
```

I am creating e.g. 3 Tasks on 3 different Threads. The Tasks are getting an ID from 1 to 3 before they are working on a data stream. This process can be aborted by pressing a button, the tasks are being closed via cancellationtoken. This is happening, I testes this by calling the status of the tasks. When I am starting the processing again, a new instance of the task-creating class is started and again, 3 tasks are created. but this time, they dont have the IDs from 1 to 3 but from 4 to 6. 2 questions are coming to my mind here:

1. Doesnt the GarbageCollection kill all tasks automatically when a token is rised? Do I have to manually finalize or dispose them?
2. When the tasks have been killed correctly by the token, how can I rest the indexer of the TaskFactory, so that the 3 new tasks will get their IDs by 1 again?

I want to use the task IDs for indexing task-specific arrays. Of course there is a workaround for this but why -- a task brings his

Answer (score 2):

A few things.  There is a common misconception that a creating a `Task` means that you're creating a new thread.  Based on your question, it appears you're creating the Tasks on a single thread.  These tasks are going to be queued and dequeued by the default scheduler (unless you've specified a custom scheduler) which is using the `ThreadPool`.  If you're familiar with that, you'll know that it will only create as many threads as needed, and will reuse them as necessary.  It's possible for you to create 10 tasks at the same time that execute on only, say, 3 threads total.

However, to directly answer your questions:

1. No.  When the `Cancel` method cancellation token source is called, it puts the token into a cancelled state, and the tasks that have been assigned the token for *that particular token source* will be canceled.  At this point, the `Task` (READ: not the thread) will be marked for a garbage collection, if *and only if* you're not holding onto any references of it, just like any other object in the runtime that can be garage collected.

   If it can be successfully collected, it will be destroyed.  The backing thread, however, is put back into the `ThreadPool`'s list of available threads.  It might be used again with another task, or, if another task is never started, the `ThreadPool` will eventually free that `Thread` and cause it to be GC'd.
2. You can't do that.  The ID's that are assigned are not actually assigned by the `TaskFactory`.  When the `Task` is started, it's not actually assigned an ID.  It will *never* be assigned an ID, unless you query `Task.Id`.  The ID is created from static int in the `Task` class that is incremented each time the ID is requested.

   Since you can't create or modify a Task's Id, I wouldn't use that to keep track of them.  Instead, keep track of them yourself in a collection of some sort, or write another class that manages them.  It wasn't what the ID property was made for, so don't try to use it that way.

Comment: hey there, thanks a lot for answer. this small "pattern" to create tasks on different threads is from a whitepaper of microsoft, i think its the one about parallel programming in .net 4.0 from stephen toub. like this, the tasks are indeed created on different threads each. i checked this by calling Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId in a thread safe method which is called by each task several times. ill see what the problem is with the task ids, i assumed they were closer connected to the task. so i gonna find another way to handle this, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rome, in almost all cases they will be on separate threads, executing in parallel, however, my point was that when using Tasks and the PCL it may re-use a thread, which means the thread ids won't change.  In that way, it's possible for 10 tasks to run on only 3 (native) threads, if they finish execution fast enough.

Comment: @Rome, In fact, there's no real relationship between `ManagedThreadId` and the native `ThreadId`, the `ManagedThreadId` can be different each time, and yet it's still running on the same native thread.  [See the note here in the remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx)

Comment: actually thread-ids are the reason why i wanted to use the task ids. the problem is more in the architecture: i have a class that holds some kernels (compiled on runtime) which are supposed to be run in parallel from each task. every task needs his own kernel. so i wanted to create the tasks in my task manager class and then they should call a method in the other class which holds the kernel[], so every task can get his by kernel[task.id]. if i put the tasks and kernels together in a dictionary, i will loose seperation of these classes. any idea how to solve such case in best practice manner?